# Weird issue regarding debugging using Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, cpu-usage

I'm a beginner in C# ,and i have a problem regarding debugging and running applications from VS 2010 ... Sometimes -for some certain projects- when i press F5 , the VS 2010 CPU usage jumps to 50% and my app. just won't run.. and nothing happen , i tried to rebuild the solution , but still , High CPU usage and no app. running at all .. i checked if there's a running app. already in the task manager but there wasn't ... all i can do , i just copy the whole code and create a new project and past the code in it , but this isn't really a solution... So can anybody help please ?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when pressing F5 (starts with debugger the **currently active** project) I get an error message. By doing it a second time, it works. I think this is a small bug in VS2010.

If you don't see an error message, can it be that your program starts, runs and closes so fast that you don't see it? Try with F11 instead of F5 to figure it out.

This could be the case for console based applications and not for the GUI apps. Is that what you mean by it works for "some" projects?

Maybe also this thread can help: [Visual studio commands don't work. ctrl + f5 doesn't run my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913054/visual-studio-commands-dont-work-ctrl-f5-doesnt-run-my-application)

Comment: well , all projects i've worked on are console applications so far , but just some of them are causing this problem , honestly i have no idea why those particular projects and no others.
I will try the F11 thing and see what happen though :)

Comment: F11 will stop on the first instruction instead of running until end or breakpoint. I hope this helps otherwise I would really not understand what's wrong. In the `output` and `build` windows is eventually also something that might help you understand what the issue is.

Comment: Is it the same thing by using the menu instead of the shortcut? I also added a link to a maybe related question.